# imagen responsive con css sin html

Tags: html, css, responsive

alguien me indica si se puede hacer y mas o menos como o si acaso darme algún enlace donde lo expliquen. La cuestión es la siguiente. Tengo una cabezera un div y dentro de este tengo otro div y en este último una imagen de cabecera, cargada desde el css, pues bien lo que yo quiero es que sea responsive pero no lo consigo porque no encuentro información de como hacerlo en css, solo encuentro información cuando la imagen es cargada en el html. ¿Alguien me ayuda aunque sea dándome alguna directriz?

Comment: Por favor añade tu código y así será más fácil ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

no se si la tienes cargada desde el CSS como fondo (background: url(foto.jpg);) si es así puede usar la función "cover" que hace que la imagen se adapte siempre al tamaño del div.
 background-size: cover;
Aquí hay un buen ejemplo:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size3

Comment: gracias amigo lo voy a mirar a ver.

Comment: Se adapta pero hasta cierto punto. Es decir no se adapta por ejemplo a tamaño de dispositivo movil. Pero bueno te lo agradezco. supongo que tendré que poner la imagen en el html como solución.

Comment: @trevol para que la ayuda sea mas certera considera tomar en cuenta mi comentario y agregar tu código, de otra manera solo estaremos adivinando

Comment: ya lo he resuelto, gracias.